# as3 change properties of TextFormat

Tags: actionscript-3, textformat

I have a dynamic text box that gets its text from the database. The size of the text is depended on the number of characters in the string I recieve. For example, if I get a 24 chars string (which is the maximum in our database), the text size should be 17p, if I get a 23 chars string, the size should then be 18p and so on.
I could create many textFormat instances for each combination, but that wouldn't be elegant.
If I have this on my code:
    var defaultFmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    defaultFmt.font = "Comic Sans MS";
    defaultFmt.size = 30;
    defaultFmt.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
can I later change the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a TextFormat object to either a selection or a `TextField.defaultTextFormat` only reads data from object once, so you'll have to construct a complete `TextFormat` object each time you need to apply a custom format. So, both approaches will likely be used, several common text formats can be stored in variables, and a custom-made object can be created each time you need to do something fancy.